# Родительское окно Java

Tags: java

имеется вопрос. Ниже представлен код:

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String list = "Введите значение";
    String words = "";

    words = showInputDialog(null, list);

    String dwords = words.toLowerCase();

    if (dwords.equals("привет")) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Вы вписали значение: "+words);
    } 
}

}
```

Что мне нужно вписать в `showMessageDialog` в первом аргументе вместо `null` чтобы при нажатии на ОК снова возвращалось окно с вводом значения, а не выполнялось закрытие программы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого Вам необходимо всю вашу итерацию обернуть в бесконечный цикл:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            String list = "Введите значение";
            String words = "";
            words = showInputDialog(null, list);
            String dwords = words.toLowerCase();
            if (dwords.equals("привет")) {
                showMessageDialog(null, "Вы вписали значение: " + words);
            }
        }
    }
```